# Apache unexpectedly shut down after start on XAMPP (Windows 7)

Tags: apache, webserver, xampp, windows-7-x64

Please note, I'm a newb so bear with me if this is just a stupid mistake.

I have XAMPP on my Win 7 laptop, no IIS, no extra MySQL stuff. However, everytime I click start for the apache module this comes up.

```
18:18:01  [Apache]  Problem detected!
18:18:01  [Apache]  Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!
18:18:01  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
18:18:01  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
18:18:01  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
18:18:01  [Apache]  Attempting to start Apache app...
18:18:02  [Apache]  Status change detected: running
18:18:02  [Apache]  Status change detected: stopped
18:18:02  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
18:18:02  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
18:18:02  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
18:18:02  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
18:18:02  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
18:18:02  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
18:18:02  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

Skype and VMWare is disconnected, nothing in Error log or Windows Event Viewer, and as far as I know, port 80 is free

Any advice would be most welcome.

Many thanks

EDIT: thanks for the answer. Turns out the Web Deploy Service issued with Microsoft WebMatrix was to blame. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error log, it is obvious that port 80 is opened

```
Open a CMD prompt and type in command: net stop was /y

Run Dialog Box (press keys Win+R) .. then type: services.msc
```

I then scrolled down to: World Wide Web Publishing Service Double clicked on it and clicked STOP (if this service status is Started)

```
Start Apache again with XAMPP :)
```

Link Ref: http://www.sitepoint.com/unblock-port-80-on-windows-run-apache/